# SQL Server : select rows with all specified values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `Products` and `Keywords`, joined by common `ID`.

```
PRODUCTS                                KEYWORDS

Prod_id    Prod_name                    Prod_id    Keyword
--------------------                    ------------------
      1    Broccoli                           1    kw1
      2    Caulifower                         1    kw2
      3    Leek                               2    kw1
      4    Spinach                            2    kw3
      5    Zucchini                           2    kw4
                                              3    kw1
                                              3    kw2
                                              3    kw4
                                              4    kw2
                                              4    kw3
                                              4    kw4
```

How do I select only those products that have both 'kw1' and 'kw2' (may have other) assigned?. In the above example that would be Broccoli and Leek. List of required keywords can be longer than two. It's probably trivial, but I can't find the way to achieve this.

If I do

```
SELECT 
    Prod_id 
FROM 
    products p
JOIN 
    keywords k ON p.prod_id = k.prod_id
WHERE 
    keyword IN ('kw1', 'kw2')
```

it selects all rows with 'kw1' OR 'kw2' (as expected) but I need 'kw1' **AND** 'kw2'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't seem to need the `products` table, if you only want the `id`.  Then, you can do what you want basically by adding a `group by` and `having` clause to your query:

```
SELECT k.Prod_id
FROM keywords k
WHERE k.keyword IN ('kw1' ,'kw2')
GROUP BY k.Prod_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT k.keyword) = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
select * from Keywords 
where Keyword = 'kw1' and Prod_id in(
    select Prod_id from Keywords where Keyword = 'kw2'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's just a couple of keywords you're searching for this is one way to do it:

```
SELECT Prod_id FROM products p
where exists (select 1 from keywords 
    where p.prod_id = k.prod_id and keyword = 'kw1') and
exists (select 1 from keywords 
    where p.prod_id = k.prod_id and keyword = 'kw2')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT p.prod_id
  FROM products p INNER JOIN keywords k
    ON p.prod_id = k.prod_id
 WHERE k.keyword IN ('kw1','kw2')
 GROUP BY p.prod_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

The other alternative would be to use `WHERE EXISTS` but I find that a bit klunky since it requires two subqueries in this case.

Comment: This will not do the trick. If there are 2 kw1 and 0 kw2 you will get that row in result.

Comment: I'm assuming that `prod_id` + `keyword` is unique, which I think is a fair assumption given the sample data. If not then one can use `COUNT(DISTINCT k.keyword)` instead of `COUNT(*)`.